# JavaScript Form Validation when false

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is really bothering me. I just want the form to not submit if the function returns false. Here is the script.

```
function checkPass(){
                          var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass');
                          var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
                          var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
                          var goodColor = "#224466";
                          var badColor = "#900000";
                          if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
                            pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
                            
                            
                            return true;
                          }else{
                            pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
                            
                            
                            return false;
                          }
                        }
```

The form still submits when I use:

```
<form onsumbit="checkPass();">
</form>
```

and when I use:

```
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="checkPass();">
</form>
```

and no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you attaching that event handler to your form?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing.  Can you clarify the form you are trying to work with?  Is this checkPass in your onsubmit function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this on the *onsubmit* event of your **form**:

```
onsubmit="return checkPass()"
```

Or this one for your *Submit* button (the input tag):

```
onclick="return checkForm()"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xhtml make sure 'onsubmit' is lowercase.

```
<form onsubmit="return checkPass()" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

As M2X says, you need to use

```
<form onsubmit="return checkPass();">
```

The reason is that when you assign an event handler as an attribute that way, what actually happens internally is that a new anonymous function is created wrapped around the code in the attribute, and that function needs to return the value that will prevent or allow the form submission.

So your original `onsubmit` attribute will be turned into:

```
function() {
    checkPass();
}
```

which executes the `checkPass` function but discards its return value. By including the `return` in the attribute, it will be turned into:

```
function() {
    return checkPass();
}
```

which will return the value returned to it by the `checkPass` function, thereby achieving the desired effect.